# Selectinput() with multiple=TRUE in Shiny app , only responds when i choose values serially

Tags: r, shiny

i have a simple shiny app and i want to create data table which will provide the rows based on the name i choose in my selectinput(). While it works normally when i choose names one after the other(first,second,third...etc) it does not respond when i choose first name, then third name, then second etc. Any suggestions?

```
nba <- data.frame(
  player = c("James", "Durant", "Curry", "Harden", "Paul", "Wade"), 
  team = c("CLEOH", "GSWOAK", "GSWOAK", "HOUTX", "HOUTX", "CLEOH"),
  day1points = c("25","23","30","41","26","20"), 
  day2points = c("24","25","33","45","26","23"),
  rating=c("1","2","3","4","5","1")
)
```

## ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- navbarPage(
  title="SADDAS",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(uiOutput("var1_select")),
             mainPanel(tableOutput("reportOutput"))
))
```

## server.r

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$var1_select<-renderUI({
    selectInput("ind_var_select","Select Names", choices =c(as.character(nba[,1] )),multiple = TRUE,selected = nba[1,1])
  })
  output$reportOutput = renderTable(
    {subset(nba[,1:3],player==input$ind_var_select)},
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)

nba <- data.frame(
  player = c("James", "Durant", "Curry", "Harden", "Paul", "Wade"), 
  team = c("CLEOH", "GSWOAK", "GSWOAK", "HOUTX", "HOUTX", "CLEOH"),
  day1points = c("25","23","30","41","26","20"), 
  day2points = c("24","25","33","45","26","23"),
  rating=c("1","2","3","4","5","1")
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title="SADDAS",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("var1_select")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("reportOutput"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$var1_select<-renderUI({
    selectInput("ind_var_select","Select Names", choices =c(as.character(nba[,1] )),multiple = TRUE,selected = nba[1,1])
  })
  output$reportOutput = renderTable({
    nba[,1:3][nba$player %in% input$ind_var_select,]
  },
  options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```